# How to Replace text from postgresql data?

Tags: postgresql, replace

My PostgreSQL data has "id" column.
This column has each item's ID

Example.

**PLPL-WIT-2009-00537**

**DE14531/11-1**

**NLRTD-2014-0603**

some of them has "/" in ID (ex.DE14531/11-1 contains "/")

I want to replace all "/" to "--"

So I tried this

```
UPDATE table_name SET id=REPLACE(id,"/","--");
```

but an error occurred.

```
ERROR:  column "/" does not exist
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use double quotes for database, schema and column names, and single quotes for data.    If you look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html, you will see the example for replace also uses single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace double quote to single quote as below:

```
UPDATE table_name SET id=REPLACE(id, '/', '--');
```